# Exclude from some of domains and websites referring my website

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, magento, link-building

My website was referred and accessed through an unwanted website. Example:

**My referrals:** Facebook, Twitter, Particular etc.

Receiving referrals from social media sites such as Facebook and Twitter is intended but not from Particular. How can I block unwanted referrals?

Comment: While reviewing visitors to my site (within Google Analytics) I noticed referrals from a porn site :-(
Is there a way to block such visitors or referring sites?

Comment: That seems to happen to all of us from time to time. I just ignore it. Generally, it is a new site spamdexing to get traffic. It only lasts a little while. It can also just be referrer spam in which case, there is no harm and no foul. It too will go away. I generally do not worry so much over these things unless it gets really out of hand. Otherwise, it will keep you forever busy! ;-) It will be like whack-a-mole!! Fun for a while, then boring and senseless.